# How to skip div using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I face a problem when apply the div expire code to the modals. When expire some modal, I need to skip the expired div and the next and previous buttons working properly. Please help me to fix the issue.

Here is the js codes I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
       id = pNode.prev(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').last().attr("id");
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
 $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
       id = pNode.next(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').first().attr("id");
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
});

$(function() {

  var current_date = new Date();

    $(".with-expiry").each(function() {
        var div_date = $(this).data('expiry');

      // wrap in Date class
      div_date = new Date(div_date);

        if(current_date.getTime()>div_date.getTime()){
                $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
  });

})
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15ds0ea7/250/) url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class to expired modals, check for them with nextAll or prevAll and select the first element on the returned list of those of two functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog:not(.expired)");
       id = pNode.prevAll(".modalDialog:not(.expired)").first().attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').last().attr("id");
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
 $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog:not(.expired)");
       id = pNode.nextAll(".modalDialog:not(.expired)").first().attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').first().attr("id");
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
});

$(function() {

  var current_date = new Date();
  
 $(".with-expiry").each(function() {
      var div_date = $(this).data('expiry');
      
      // wrap in Date class
      div_date = new Date(div_date);
  
    if(current_date.getTime()>div_date.getTime()){
    $(this).hide();
          $(this).addClass('expired');
      } else {
         $(this).show();
          $(this).removeClass('expired');
      }
  });
})
```

```css
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
.getAssignment{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <a href="#openModal3" id="openModalBtn" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 05, 2019 12:00:00"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg">open modal3</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <a href="#openModal4" id="openModalBtn" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 05, 2019 12:00:00"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg">open modal4</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <a href="#openModal5" id="openModalBtn"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg">open modal5</a>
   </div>
</div>

<a href="#openModal5" id="openModalBtn">open modal5</a>


<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
       <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div> 
    <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal3" class="modalDialog with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 05, 2015 12:00:00">
    <div> 
     <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 3</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal4" class="modalDialog" >
    <div> 
      <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 4</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal5" class="modalDialog">
    <div> 
        <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 5</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
    var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
      id = pNode.prev(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
      $('.modalDialog').last().attr("id");

    var prevModalResolver = function(id) {
      var expiry = $('#' + id).data('expiry');
      var current_date = new Date();
      var div_date = new Date(expiry);
      if (div_date.getTime() < current_date.getTime()) {
        let prev_id = $('#' + id).prev(".modalDialog").attr("id");
        return prevModalResolver(prev_id);
      } else {
        return id;
      }

    };

    var prev_id = prevModalResolver(id)




    window.location.href = "#" + prev_id;
  });
  $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
    var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
      id = pNode.next(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
      $('.modalDialog').first().attr("id");


    var nextModalResolver = function(id) {
      var expiry = $('#' + id).data('expiry');
      var current_date = new Date();
      var div_date = new Date(expiry);
      if (div_date.getTime() < current_date.getTime()) {
        let next_id = $('#' + id).next(".modalDialog").attr("id");
        return nextModalResolver(next_id);
      } else {
        return id;
      }

    };

    var next_id = nextModalResolver(id)


    window.location.href = "#" + next_id;
  });
});

$(function() {

  var current_date = new Date();

  $(".with-expiry").each(function() {
    var div_date = $(this).data('expiry');

    // wrap in Date class
    div_date = new Date(div_date);

    if (current_date.getTime() > div_date.getTime()) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });



})
```

See the updated JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/15ds0ea7/259/